# Unusual Error in python: 'TypeError: o is not a valid validator because it is not callable'

Tags: python, validation, flask, post

When I use Postman to make a POST request of ("{url}/posts/"), it runs the add_post method below, and I get a strange error I've never seen before:

'TypeError: o is not a valid validator because it is not callable'

I'm attempting to validate the request json, and I'm very confident this is where the error came in because everything worked before I tried validating. I am trying to use flask_inputs to validate the request, and I copied several online documentations exactly.  However, this results in the error I stated above, and I'm not sure why.  Any suggestions help!

```
import json

from flask import Flask
from flask import jsonify
from flask import request
from flask_inputs import Inputs
from flask_inputs.validators import JsonSchema

app = Flask(__name__)

post_data = dict()
post_counter = 0

@app.route("/posts/", methods=["POST"])
def add_post():
    global post_counter
    check = PostCheck(request)
    
    if not check.validate():
        return json.dumps({"success": False, "errors": check.errors})

    body = json.loads(request.data)
    title = body.get("title")
    username = body.get("username")

    data = {
        "id": post_counter,
        "title": title, 
        "username": username
    }

    post_data[post_counter] = data
    post_counter += 1
    return json.dumps({"success": True, "data": data}), 200

class PostCheck(Inputs):
    validation_schema = {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "title": {"type": "string"},
            "username": {"type": "string"}
        }
    }
    json = [JsonSchema(schema={"type":"object"})]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000, debug=True)
```

Below is the full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2309, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/serge/Documents/AppDev/Learn/backend/pa1/src/app.py", line 79, in add_post
    check = PostCheck(request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_inputs/inputs.py", line 36, in __init__
    fields[field] = Field(validators=validators)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wtforms/fields/core.py", line 43, in __new__
    return UnboundField(cls, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wtforms/fields/core.py", line 365, in __init__
    self.field_class.check_validators(validators)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wtforms/fields/core.py", line 167, in check_validators
    raise TypeError("{} is not a valid validator because it is not "
TypeError: o is not a valid validator because it is not callable
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your post and give us the **full text** of the traceback/error.

Comment: Just did that thanks

Comment: I'm just shooting in the dark here, but in `PostCheck()` you use `json` as a variable, when it is also the name of a module you're importing. Perhaps changing the name of that variable will help?

Answer (score 0):

This is where your problem is:

```
    validation_schema = {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "title": {"type": "string"},
            "username": {"type": "string"}
        }
    }
```

Even though you're not using it, it's still a class variable and json_inputs is trying to use it as a validator. To be clear, **all** class attributes defined on a json_inputs class are expected to be validators.

So you need to do one of these:

```
validation_schema = {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "title": {"type": "string"},
        "username": {"type": "string"}
    }
}

class PostCheck(Inputs):
    json = [JsonSchema(schema={"type":"object"})]
```

or

```
class PostCheck(Inputs):
    json = [JsonSchema(schema={
        'type': 'object',
        'properties': {
            'name': {'type': 'string'}
        }
    })]
```